# How to use active characters to create hyperlinks with hyperref inside a PDF?

Tags: hyperref, programming

I want to create links inside a pdf and actually I use `\hypertarget{label}{target caption}` and `\hyperlink{label}{link caption}` with the package hyperref. Perhaps it's possible to use something like `|name|` to create `\hypertarget{label_name}{name}` and `||name||` (or `§name§`) to create `\hyperlink{label_name}{name}`. Is it possible ? 
Perhaps do you know a package to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\catcode`|=\active
\protected\def|{\ifmmode\vert\else\expandafter\alain@vert\fi}
\def\alain@vert{\@ifnextchar|{\alain@link}{\alain@target}}
\def\alain@link|#1||{\hyperlink{label_#1}{#1}}
\def\alain@target#1|{\hypertarget{label_#1}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hypertarget: |name|

$|x|$

\newpage

Hyperlink: ||name||

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I need to study your code tomorrow but it' certainly the good answer

Comment: Thanks egreg it's fine! What's the best way to manage this with `\AtBeginDocument{\MakeShortVerb{\|}}` With shortvrb package I have `\DeleteShortVerb` because sometimes the symbol `|` appears in my doc as mark of angles. So  I need to change the active character but what other precautions should I take?

Comment: @AlainMatthes You can't have `|` doing a double role: either you use it for hyperlinks or for verbatim.

Comment: yes I understand that !

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to create a macro like in your answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184438/how-do-you-define-macros-to-toggle-a-character-active-and-define-a-macro-for-it to redefine  the correct catcode.