# how to replace matrix element by color box

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I replace the matrix element by colored squared box ? Suppose I have  a 10x10 matrix with entries{+1,-1}. I want to put a black square box for +1 and red square box got -1 which will give me a design.
Anyone can provide me clear idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 11):

Below I present two possibilities.

1. You don't even need the `1`s; it's enough to have an array of `+` and `-` characters:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fancyvrb}
   \usepackage{xcolor}

   \makeatletter
   \newenvironment{MyVerb}
     {
       \def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\<\do\>\do\,\do\'}
       \catcode`+=\active
       \catcode`-=\active
       \setlength\fboxsep{6pt}
       \offinterlineskip
       \VerbatimEnvironment
       \begin{Verbatim}
     }
     {\end{Verbatim}}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \begin{MyVerb}[defineactive=%
       \def+{\colorbox{black}{\phantom{a}}}
       \def-{\colorbox{red!70!black}{\phantom{a}}}]
   +-+-+-+-+-
   -+-+-+-+-+
   +-+-+-+-+-
   -+-+-+-+-+
   +-+-+-+-+-
   -+-+-+-+-+
   +-+-+-+-+-
   -+-+-+-+-+
   +-+-+-+-+-
   -+-+-+-+-+
   \end{MyVerb}

   \begin{MyVerb}[defineactive=%
       \def+{\colorbox{black}{\phantom{a}}}
       \def-{\colorbox{red!70!black}{\phantom{a}}}]
   +---+---+-
   --+---+---
   -+++-+++-+
   --+---+---
   +---+---+-
   ++-+++-+++
   +---+---+-
   --+---+---
   -+++-+++-+
   --+---+---
   \end{MyVerb}

   \begin{MyVerb}[defineactive=%
       \def+{\colorbox{black}{\phantom{a}}}
       \def-{\colorbox{red!70!black}{\phantom{a}}}]
   ++++++++++
   +---++---+
   +-+-++-+-+
   +++-++-+++
   ----++----
   ----++----
   +++-++-+++
   +-+-++-+-+
   +---++---+
   ++++++++++
   \end{MyVerb}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   This answer is a variation of [`my answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176746) to [Is there a way to make a certain character in a Verbatim have a certain formatting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176739).
2. Here's a different approach using this time the [`collcell`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell) package:
       \documentclass{article}
       \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
       \usepackage{collcell}

   ```
   \def\Side{8pt}

   \newcommand\ColCell[1]{%
     \ifnum#1=-1\relax
       \gdef\mycolor{red!70!black}
     \else
     \ifnum#1=1\relax
       \gdef\mycolor{black}
     \fi\fi 
     \expandafter\expandafter\cellcolor{\mycolor}%
       \parbox[c][\dimexpr\Side+2\tabcolsep\relax][c]{\Side}{}%
   }

   \newcolumntype{E}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\collectcell\ColCell}p{\Side}<{\endcollectcell}}

   \begin{document}

   \noindent\begin{tabular}{*{10}{E}}
   +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   \end{tabular}\qquad        
   \noindent\begin{tabular}{*{10}{E}}
   +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 \\
   -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   \end{tabular}\bigskip

   \noindent\begin{tabular}{*{10}{E}}
   +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 \\
   -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 \\
   +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 \\
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: @Erfan You're welcome. Don't forget that, after a sensible wait, you can accept an answer that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).